# Adding link type to Redactor Rich Editor

Tags: redactor, richtext, link

I have a Craft CMS powered site which has "Suppliers" set up as a user group. A route is being used to link through to these suppliers on the frontend; example.com/supplier/loremipsum.

Is it possible to add an option to the link button on the Rich editor field, that would allow me to choose a user from the *supplier* user group? Much like the "Link to an entry" option.

[image: Link to an entry]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with a [custom plugin](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins) that used the [addRichTextLinkOptions](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#addRichTextLinkOptions) to add extra options to that dropdown.

You can use https://pluginfactory.io to generate boilerplate plugin code to get you up and running quickly.

Comment: Ahhh ok great, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @ChrisMoorst did you end with a working plugin? I'm doing something related and I'd love to see an example