# Redactor // "Link to an entry" not available

Tags: redactor, link

maybe someone has an idea?

The **Redactor Rich Editor does not show "Link to an entry"** - only "Insert link" is available (see screenshot).

I'm pretty sure this might work, like in this post:
[Adding link type to Redactor Rich Editor](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/22395/adding-link-type-to-redactor-rich-editor)

Using the **Redactor standard config**, **Craft 4.4.2**, **Redactor 3.0.3**.

Thanks a lot for a hint! :)

[image]

Comment: Can you post the full redactor config used by the field?

Comment: It's solved, thanks a lot for your support, Moritz!

Answer (score 1):

Does your site have any sections? The link to entries option is only visible if there is at least one section to select entries from.

To find out more, you can use the [`EVENT_REGISTER_LINK_OPTIONS`](https://github.com/craftcms/redactor/blob/main/src/Field.php#L49) event. The property `$event->linkOptions` should include the *Link to an Entry* option, but [only if the site has any sections](https://github.com/craftcms/redactor/blob/main/src/Field.php#L501-L509).

Answer (score 1):

Oh my ... sometimes it's just too easy. :/

The items in the Redactor Link Options were just **hidden with CSS**.